# How to do a final DB push when a Tomcat shutdown occurs?

Tags: java, jersey, java-8, tomcat7, guice

I have this web application, which buffers stuff and then batch inserts said stuff into the DB.
Now I want to be able to do a final batch insert whenever a Tomcat shutdown event is happening, so that I don't loose my stuff.

My app is a pretty simple Guice+Jersey API.

I've tried overriding `contextDestroy` of `GuiceServletContextListener` but it ends up in an NPE, because my injected dependencies seem to have been GC'ed at that point.

Comment: Too broad, really? o_O This question is written exactly to have a single correct answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: If you deem this to be too broad, can you at least tell me where I should be more specific?

Comment: Where does the NPE occur? It's unlikely that the injected dependencies are `null`.  It's more likely that tomcat is trying to prevent memory leaks and is preventing new JDBC connections from being made.  But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC can only collect resources when there are zero hard references to some instance.  I think the `GuiceServletContextListener` is still your best bet. At this point Tomcat is trying to clean up resources before it attempts to let the GC reclaim the ClassLoader that your app is running in. Everything you need should still be available as long as you have a hard reference.

When you create your `Injector`, hold on to a reference of a `Provider` that returns a class that does your cleanup.  When `contextDestroyed` is called, get an instance of the cleanup class from the provider and run the logic.

**Setups**

1. Write a cleanup class, containing all of the needed dependencies.
2. Bind this cleanup class to guice.
3. When you create the `Injector`, keep an instance of the provider that returns the cleanup class in your `GuiceServletContextListener` (Don't keep an instance of the `Injector`. It contains the entire dependency tree).
4. When the `contextDestroyed` method is called, use the provider to get an instance of the cleanup class and run the logic.

Comment: You we're absolutely correct that the `GuiceServletContextListener` is the way to go. Turns out that I messed up with the context listeners and now the `contextDestroyed` hook actually works :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is a JVM shutdown and you could register a shutdown hook to the JVM to let you execute your code when it is shutting down, something like this-

```
Thread shutdownHook = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        { 
            //Do your work here
        }
    };
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
```